# ::after for inline HTML email?

Tags: html, css, email

```
.banner  {
  width: 34px;
  height: 52px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.banner:after { # How can I make this same behavior work inline?
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 24px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 9px solid white;
}
```

This is what is produces:

[image]

How can I create this shape inline?

Everything I tried didn't work because it seems `position` and negative margins aren't supported in email.

Comment: create a `div` inside the `banner` as the last child and apply the styles inline...

Comment: @kukkuz You shouldn't  use `<div>` elements in HTML mails

Comment: i dont think you can apply after inline better use an image

Comment: @RudiUrbanek I've used the above image too, but then I can't overlay the text ontop of that either without running into the same problem with `position` and negative margins

Comment: **You can't.**  Pseudo-elements aren't in the DOM (or email) and so cannot receive inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as an image because pseudo-element content does not appear in the DOM. These elements are not real elements. As such, they are not accessible to most assistive devices. So, never use pseudo-elements to generate content that is critical to the usability or accessibility of your pages.

[Read more](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)