# embedding HTML style image in email

Tags: html

Dears

I'm trying to send an email and embed an image with Place Text in Image using HTML, but when receiving the email message the text is off the image,,

I really hope I can find the solution. I attached the code below

many thanks & best regards

should appear like this
[image]

but appears in the email like this
[image]

```html
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/007/515/533/original/colourful-particle-moving-on-balck-background-blue-smoke-moving-against-black-background-moving-particles-blur-on-black-background-moving-particles-blur-on-black-background-free-video.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you using to send your email with? Have you checked that the HTML looks the same after receiving the mail?

Comment: I am using outlook, the text is not in same positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the expected behavior in email styling. Basically not all css properties have grip in styling the page as the browser does to web pages. Personally, I always prefer `<table>` over `<div>` in emails, because it always gives me more grip on the way the user sees my email.

Having said that, you may have a look at https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/  to see what elements / tags / properties work on all major email clients. Its a very handy guide.

My recommendation is to design a table with say, 3 rows and 3 columns, Place your text in corresponding columns and apply background image property to every cell `<td>` using CSS.

example;

```
<td style="background: #000000 url("http://example.com/image.png") repeat; border: 0; margin: 0"></td>
```

In addition to that, https://javier.xyz/img2css/ this tool converts images to css.

You may also go through this SO question as well;

[How to Put Text Over an Image (in email)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422875/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css styles in html code directly, don't make css styles and specify on html code.

like bolow:

```
<div style="color:green;" id="div"></div>
```

instead of

```
<style>
    #div {
        color:green;
    }
</style>
    
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using inline styles instead of an external stylesheet. Like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 16px;">Bottom Left</div>
```

**What you CAN'T do:**

- Include a section with styles. Apple Mail.app supports it, but Gmail and Hotmail do not, so it's a no-no. Hotmail will support a style section in the body but Gmail still doesn't.
- Link to an external stylesheet. Not many email clients support this, best to just forget it.
- Background-image / Background-position. Gmail is also the culprit on this one.
- Clear your floats. Gmail again.
- Margin. Yep, seriously, Hotmail ignores margins. Basically any CSS positioning at all doesn't work.
- Font-anything. Chances are Eudora will ignore anything you try to declare with fonts.
- There are quite a few more things you should be aware of. For a great complete list of what online email services support what, check out this article at Xavier Frenette.

**What you CAN do:**
In two words, inline styles. It's not as awful, inline styles are not nearly as egregious as using them on a website.